# loop in answers with javascript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, loops

this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input").focus(function () {
        $(this).css('outline-color', '#559FFF');
        $(this).blur(function () {
            $(this).css("outline-color", "#FF0000");
        });
    });
    $("input").click(function () {
        var value = $(this).val(function () {
            $(this).html("");
        });
    });
    $(".awesome").click(function () {
        var toStore = $("input[name=name]").val();
        if (!/^[A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z]+$/.test(toStore)) {
            alert("You Must Put a Valid Name");
        } else {
            $("#contain").children().fadeOut(1000);
            $("#contain").delay(1000).queue(function () {
                $("#contain").append("<h1>Welcome to My Quiz : " + toStore + "</br>" +
                    "Youll Get 10 Questions To Answer </br> " +
                    "Here Is the First One:Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom? </h1>");

                var allQuestions = {
                    outquestions:{
                        question1 : {    quest: "Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?",
                            choices: ["David Cameron","Gordon Brown","Winston Churchill","Tony Blair"],
                            correctAnswer: "David Cameron"},
                        question2 : {    quest: "whats dad name?",
                            choices: ["David ","Gordon ","Winston ","Tony "],
                            correctAnswer: "David"}
                    },
                    correctAnswers: 0
                };

                var outquestions = allQuestions["outquestions"];
                for (var question in outquestions) {
                    $("#contain").append("<p>(outquestions[question][quest]</p>");
                    for (var choice in outquestions[question]["choices"]) {
                        $("h1").append("<form><input type='radio' name=question value=choice></form>");
                    }
                }
                $("#contain").append("<form><input type='submit' value='submit'></form>");
                $("#contain").on("click", "input[name=submit]", function () {
                });

            });
        }
    });
});
```

i want this section to loop through the questions and write between with:

```
var outquestions = allQuestions["outquestions"];
                    for (var question in outquestions) {
                        $("#contain").append("<p>(outquestions[question][quest]</p>");
                        for (var choice in outquestions[question]["choices"]) {
                            $("h1").append("<form><input type='radio' name=question value=choice></form>");
                        }
                    }
                    $("#contain").append("<form><input type='submit' value='submit'></form>");
```

afterwads i want all my answers of the qestion that is been looped Any given time to display the radio buttons and the value of the radio buttons buttons instaed i get what you see in the picture.
what is wrong here?[image]

Comment: lots of problems within your code. Can't troubleshoot code based on an image. Provide html and create a demo in jsfiddle.net. Image provided is worthless

Comment: yeah i know my coding is not perfect and orgenized im working of that :)

Comment: It's very easy to cheat on a quiz like this, since you cannot prevent someone from looking at the JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var outquestions = allQuestions["outquestions"];
    for (var question in outquestions) {
        $("#contain").append("<p>(outquestions[question][quest]</p>");
        for (var choice in outquestions[question]["choices"]) {
            $("#contain").append("<h1><input type='radio' name=question value=choice></h1>");
        }
    }
    $("#contain").append("<input type='submit' value='submit'>");
    $("#contain").on("click", "input[name=submit]", function () {});
```

I havent tested the above code, but it should put your options in between your questions.

Comment: also change the following line
 $("#contain").append("<p>(outquestions[question][quest]</p>");
to this
 $("#contain").append("<p>(outquestions[question]['quest']</p>");

Answer (score 0):

i made some changes thas for you guys and some thinking of myself here is the result of my code:

```
var allQuestions = {
                    outquestions:{
                        question1 : {    quest: "Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?",
                            choices: ["David Cameron","Gordon Brown","Winston Churchill","Tony Blair"],
                            correctAnswer: "David Cameron"}
                    },
                    correctAnswers: 0
                };

                var outquestions = allQuestions["outquestions"];
                for (var question in outquestions) {
                    $("#contain").append("<h1>" + outquestions[question]['quest'] + "</h1>");
                    for (var choice in outquestions[question]["choices"]) {
                        $("#contain").append("<p><input type='radio' name=question value=choice>" +outquestions[question]["choices"][choice] + "</p>");
                    }
                }
```

thanks for helping guys.